# How can I remove (... and digits from columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df is a dataframe that contains countries and their details. Some countries are name with () and numbers, for example Bolivia(blabala, jab s asas) or Bolivia21. My function should return Bolivia in all cases. My code is returning an error, but I feel like the results are getting filled in the index... ? here it is:

```
df.loc[df['Country']] = df.loc[df['Country']].str.split('(')[0]
df.loc[df['Country']] = df.loc[df['Country']].str.split('\d')[0]
```

Comment: Try `df['Country'].str.extract(r'[\w\s]+')`

Comment: returns a ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups,

Comment: Put round parentheses around the whole pattern `r'([\w\s]+)'`

Comment: Worked ! Thanks, can you please explain how it works?

Comment: This is more a Regular Expression problem rather than a Pandas problem, so check out this here https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python

Comment: Well.. I spoke too soon, it is still not working.. the digits are not getting filtered.. split('(')[0] works and returns the right value, however split('\d')[0] returns the value as it is... any ideas?

Comment: Do I need to install any package to use regex?

Comment: `df['Country'].str.extract(r'([^\d]+)')` to remove numeric values. Try [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for Regular Expressions.

Comment: Thank you, that worked and for the ( I used, (r'([^\(]+)'). Weird thing... if I loop over the dataframe and check the values using .contains and then change them using .loc[index,['Country']] many values do not change... any idea why?